# Question about Grant (DCL) in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem with understanding what exatly i do wrong. Impossibile to give access to another user via role. Example:

System user:

```
create table testtable (id number);--Table TESTTABLE created
create role testrole;--Role TESTROLE created
grant insert on testtable to testrole;--Grant succeeded
grant testrole to hr;--Grant succeeded
```

Hr user:

```
insert into system.testtable values(1)
```

> SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: You should **never** create tables in the SYSTEM or SYS schemas. Never.

Comment: Thanks for response. This is only for test. I try with any other users and result the same.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: It works, just reconnect the user `hr`.

The [documentations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3) says

> *"If you grant a role to a user, then the database makes the role available to the user. The user can immediately enable the role and exercise the privileges in the privilege domain of the role."*

So your user `hr` needs to enable the role before being able to use it:

```
insert into a.testtable values(1);
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

SELECT * FROM session_roles;
no rows selected

SET ROLE testrole;
Role set.

SELECT * FROM session_roles;
TESTROLE

insert into a.testtable values(1);
1 row created.
```

Roles are normally automatically enabled during log on, so you have to do the enabling only if hr has a session open while it gets the role granted. Standard procedure is to disconnect/reconnect the user if there are problems with new roles.